# Completely rounded vs Rounded rectangle buttons

Tags: mobile, buttons, design

I was curious to know why at some places completely rounded buttons are used and other places of the same application there are rounded rectangle buttons?

As far as I could understand, small Rounded-rectangle buttons might visually look like a badge, but then why not use completely rounded buttons for full width button as well? Is it matter of design language or there is a deep logic?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think when button size is small we normally use completely rounded side edges as the side edges of button are too small to make just their corners rounded..When button size is bigger and we want to  put more focus on the content inside the button we use rounded corners rectangle button.

Comment: Not sure I agree. Why would you _not_ want to focus on the content of the small button? Why use different radiuses?

Comment: @Luciano Not sure but I think when button size is small we normally use completely rounded side edges as the side edges of button are too small to make just their corners rounded.A smaller button will look more beautiful with rounded side edges rather than rounded corners

Comment: So now you're saying it's just aesthetics... Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

To be blunt, this is another example for Apple needlessly creating inconsistencies in their UIs. Consistency is good for our users, because it reduces cognitive overhead in interacting with our applications. In that sense, a button should look like a button should look like a button. Regardless of size, etc.

It does make sense to introduce slightly different appearances to indicate specific states, such as "enabled/available" vs. "disabled/unavailable", and to guide the user to the most likely action via a "primary" or "call-to-action" button that has more visual prominence than other buttons on a screen.

But if the user has to wonder what is a button, and what isn't, the design is flawed. And, IMHO, that's exactly the case in the above example. One could argue that the rounded shape indicates the call-to-action on this screen. Still, the much brighter color would have provided enough indication of that fact already.